# "Monoid objects" without points

Tags: ct.category-theory

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a category with binary Cartesian products. Let's say that a map $f : X \to Y$ is *constant* if, for every pair of maps $g,h : A \to X$, maps $f \circ g$ and $f \circ h$ are equal. Now, we can define a "monoid object without points" in $\mathbf{C}$ as follows: it is an object $X$ together with a map $* : X \times X \to X$ and a constant map $e : X \to X$ such that $*$ is associative in the usual sense and both compositions $X \xrightarrow{\langle id, e \rangle} X \times X \overset{*}\to X$ and $X \xrightarrow{\langle e, id \rangle} X \times X \overset{*}\to X$ are equal to the identity morphism. We also can define a "group object without points" in a similar way.

If $\mathbf{C}$ has a terminal object and there is a map $x : 1 \to X$, then $X$ is a monoid object since we can define the neutral element as $1 \overset{x}\to X \overset{e}\to X$. Moreover, this defines a bijection between the set of monoid structures and "monoid without points" structures. In particular, the only "monoid objects without points" in $\mathbf{Set}$ are usual monoids and the empty set, but there might be more examples in an arbitrary category.

> Is there a name for such "monoid" and "group" objects? Are there any interesting examples of them? Were they considered in the literature?

The reason I'm asking is that (I believe) I have an example of a locale which might not have points but has a structure of a group in the sense I described.

Comment: If the coequalizer $T$ of the projections $X\times X\rightrightarrows X$ exists then $e$ determines a morphism $T\to X$ so that $X$ will become a "usual" monoid in ${\mathbf C}/T$.

Comment: Assuming classical logic, the map from any a non zero locale to the point is an open surjection, hence a regular epimorphism this implies that any constant map factor through the point and hence this notion is in this case equivalent to the usual notion of monoid. In other category or constructively the notion can be non trivial and interesting though. I never saw it before.

Comment: @SimonHenry Yes, I'm working constructively. Maybe this notion is useful only in this setting (at least for locales it is).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe there are non-trivial examples of this concept. Assume that $e: X \to X$ is a constant map, then $e$ is idempotent. Any category can be embedded fully faithfully into a [Cauchy complete](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cauchy+complete+category) category, so we can assume that $e$ splits as $X \xrightarrow{p} T \xrightarrow{i} X$ with $p\circ i=1_T$. I claim that $T$ is a <s>terminal</s> subterminal object. Indeed, let $f,g: A \to T$, then
$$\begin{eqnarray}
A \xrightarrow f T & = & 
A \xrightarrow f \left( T \xrightarrow i X \xrightarrow p T\right) \xrightarrow 1 \left(T \xrightarrow i X \xrightarrow p T \right) \\
& = &
A \xrightarrow f T \xrightarrow i \left(X \xrightarrow p T \xrightarrow 1 T \xrightarrow i X \right) \xrightarrow p T \\
& = &
A \xrightarrow g T \xrightarrow i \left(X \xrightarrow p T \xrightarrow 1 T \xrightarrow i X \right) \xrightarrow p T \\
& = & A \xrightarrow g T
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Regarding your supposed example of a locale, it is most likely that what you have is either a groupoid in locales or a localic group over some non-trivial base.

Comment: There might be $A$ without any maps to $X$, so $T$ is only subterminal. There are categories with lots of subterminals but without a terminal. What is true is that $X$ is a monoid in the slice over $T$ (more or less as in my comment).

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Are there idempotent-complete examples of such categories? In any case, $T$ will be terminal for the subcategory of objects that admit a map to $X$, which is as good as we can expect.

Comment: The empty set is an exemple in the category of sets. If G is a group object in $C/X$ and $X \rightarrow Y $ is a mono then G is a non trivial exemple of the notion in $C/Y$

Comment: Hum... So what you proved is that in Cauchy complete category those are exactly the monoid objects of slice categories by subterminal objects. Nice !

Comment: An example: elementary toposes and geometric morphisms. It has image factorizations, so in particular idempotents split. The topos of finite sets, as well as sets below an inaccessible cardinal, are subterminals.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე : you mean logical morphisms, not geometric morphisms. (those inclusion functor do not have adjoints)

Comment: @SimonHenry Sorry could you elaborate about inclusion functor? I had in mind geometric morphisms, if there is a geometric morphism to a well-pointed topos like finite sets or all sets, it is unique (since every object there is a coproduct of terminals). As for logical functors - is not the trivial topos terminal there?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე : My point was just that the inclusion of the category of finite sets or of sets smaller than an inaccessible cardinals are not geometric morphisms because they do not have an adjoint. But they are logical morphisms. I agree that the category of sets is not terminal in the category of logical morphisms.